# Artisan Console command not working in 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am new in laravel. I was trying to make a custom `artisan` command for creating tables in my test project.I followed [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-commands) but my command was not on the artisan list.Event I tried same example given in that link but its  also not worked. I dont know why its happening.

**I DID THIS:**

1)  Run this command  `php artisan make:console SendEmails`

2) Put complete class code in `app/Console/Commands/SendEmails.php` file

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\User;
use App\DripEmailer;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class SendEmails extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'email:send {user}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send drip e-mails to a user';

    /**
     * The drip e-mail service.
     *
     * @var DripEmailer
     */
    protected $drip;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @param  DripEmailer  $drip
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(DripEmailer $drip)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->drip = $drip;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->drip->send(User::find($this->argument('user')));
    }
}
```

Please help me let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just forgot to **Register your command**.

This part: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#registering-commands.

Open `app/Console/Kernel.php` and add you command class in `$commands` array.

like this :

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\SendEmails::class
];
```

That's it.